# How to obtain specific information from the Json array

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I get this array in the log how i can get the district data (the bold in yellow).

image at the link (can't add image)

[image link of the array data in the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPjCL.png)

Comment: [Please consider replacing or supplementing images consisting primarily of text with plain text versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

```js
items[0].address.district
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
items[0]["address"]["district"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. It depends on your need.

1. if you want to get the district of first item, then.

   `const district = items[0].address.district;`
2. if you want to get the list of districts from your list, then

   `const districts = items.map(item => item.address.district);`